# How do I make a field conditional based on an answer in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint 2013 list which has an "Other" drop down list. I would like to make a field conditionally appear if the user selects "other" within that list. I know that I can have the field appear fillable but my boss does not want that. They would like it so that the specify box only appears when "other" is selected. Is there an easy way to do this OOTB or with SharePoint Designer?

Thanks in advance.
Kim

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Nintex forms, by Rules Engine. Please refer below links.

[Show/Hide fields in Nintex](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1074)

If you don't want a Nintex form, You can add a content Editor/Script editor in the page, and capture the On Change event of the Drop down. So that you can Show/Hide any fields. In this case, you can get the any field values by its title. The DOM element title for all the fields is same as the "Title" (Display text) of the field. If the field is "Required", the field DOM element title will like "<"Required">". For example Title field DOM element will be a input field with the type of Text and the title property of the element will be "Title Required" . So you can get the value by using it.

For Ex:
My Field Name is "Other"  and it is required and Type of DropDown. If i need to capture the onchange event of the field means i need to do like below.

```
$(select[title='Other Required']).change(function() {
    if(this.val()=="")
      {
        //your code goes here
      }
});
```

If that field is not required.

```
$(select[title='Other']).change(function() {
 if(this.val()=="")
 {
   //your code goes here
 }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Let me know if this helps.
Thanks.